# Erro com AjaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ao fazer `.ajaxSubmit()` de um formulário com uma `input type="file"` obtenho sempre o erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).data(...) is not a function

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("guardarDocComprovaticoProdOSCli", "OrdemServicos_Clientes", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSaveFile", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="filepath" id="filepath" />
    <br />
}
```

Função JS:

```
function guardarDocComprovaticoProdOSCli() {
    if ($('#filepath').val() != "") {
        $("#formSaveFile").ajaxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            data: { idProdutoOSCli: window.idProdutoOSCli },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(b);
                alert(c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult guardarDocComprovaticoProdOSCli(int idProdutoOSCli)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase filepath = (HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files[0];
    var nameFile = "" + idProdutoOSCli + "_AnexoComprovatioProdOSCli_" + filepath.FileName + "";
    ...
    return Json("Doc. carregado", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

Obtenho este erro antes de ir para a função no *Controller*, onde passa tudo corretamente e funciona tudo (guarda ficheiro, entre outras tarefas que estou a fazer). Mas como queria usar o `success` estou com este problema... No `error` do `.ajaxSubmit()` também não trás informação relevante.

Comment: Cesar, o problema é nessa função mesmo?

Comment: Sim @renan. É mesmo quando clico num botão para chamar a função `guardarDocComprovaticoProdOSCli()`

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery está usando?

Comment: @GuilhermeNagatomo 1.10.3

Comment: Isso está parecendo mais um erro de falta de biblioteca jquery.